# How to fix a MySQL syntax error when deploying a working Play application to CloudBees?

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, cloudbees

I have very simple Play application that illustrates the use of MySQL (rather than the default H2) database available here:

https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/play-example-mysql

The README file explains the steps required to run the application locally using a local installation of MySQL. **It works fine locally.**

I have been trying unsuccessfully to get this application to work on CloudBees.  My basic strategy has been:

1. Use the CloudBees Play 2 ClickStart to create a sample app, db, repo, and build system.
2. Edit the build file to refer to my github repository.
3. Rebuild and redeploy.

More complete instructions on this strategy are available [here](http://ics-software-engineering.github.io/play-example-continuous-integration/).

When I go through this process, the system builds and deploys, but gets a MySQL syntax error in the application console when I attempt to retrieve the home page:

```
[ [37minfo [0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/play-example-mys
[ [31merror [0m] play - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sequence page_retrieval_seq' at line 1 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000]
Oops, cannot start the server.
  @6f3k8cj6c: Database 'default' is in inconsistent state!
    at play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.checkEvolutionsState(Evolutions.scala:177)
```

This is a curious error because the syntax error "sequence page_retrieval_seq" is quite similar to one of the lines generated by Play in 1.sql when the database is the default (H2):

```
create sequence page_retrieval_seq
```

Unfortunately, this line is not actually in my 1.sql file, and I do not get this error when I run the system locally.  I am running MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.12, for osx10.7 (x86_64).

I recognize that for production use, it is not advisable to enable automatic evolutions, but that is not the problem I want to solve here. My goal is for the CloudBees application to provide a snapshot of the latest working version of the code, and for evolutions to work on CloudBees MySQL just like they work for my local MySQL installation.

I have tried the steps outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783586/connect-computer-database-jpa-play-2-1-sample-application-with-mysql) but it does not work on CloudBees, and anyway my current code already works correctly on a local installation of MySQL.

Why does my simple Play application not deploy correctly on CloudBees, and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you try it with "play start" locally - just trying to narrow versions of mysql. I saw it work locally, nothing to do with cloudbees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with play running evolutions incorrectly when ebean involved when running play in "production mode"

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1410

I have tested evolutions and they work even in production mode as long as ebean isn't used.

In any case, running evolutions in a production app is less than advisable, which is probably why this bug hasn't been picked up until now.

I updated the docs: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework with info on connecting to the database from anywhere, so you can run evolutions from the desktop or from Jenkins etc.

So run in something closer to play framework prod mode run "play start" to see this behavior for yourself.

Also, it appears JPA has wider use for ORM: https://github.com/typesafehub/play-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Yeah im wrong, mis-read!

====================

As far as I know MySQL does not support sequences.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-general.html#qandaitem-B-1-1-6

```
mysql> create sequence test;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sequence blag' at line 1
```

Comment: Agreed, that's the symptom of the problem. My question is: why does CloudBees deployment result in that syntax error when (a) "create sequence" does not exist anywhere in the application code, and (b) that error does not occur when deploying locally?

Comment: Hmm I see, something similar is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233423/play-framework-2-0-1-keeps-trying-to-evolve-wrong-database-type

Comment: Yes, I think that question is generated by the same bug in Play 2.x.  Basically, although the evolution script (i.e. 1.sql) has the correct MySQL syntax (including the use of auto_increment), Play (or EBean?) attempts to invoke H2 specific SQL (create sequence). I've also tried settings the EBean property datasource.default to mysql (see http://www.avaje.org/ebean/getstarted_props.html#props) but this did not prevent Play from trying to execute the create sequence command.

Comment: Michael has done some good investigations and filed https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1410

Comment: @PhilipJohnson this seems to only happen when running via play dist, play start - production mode. Play run is ok it seems (at least of 2.1.2)